# Why in Android Studio there is one okay looking form and blue looking one?

Tags: android, forms, android-studio

Why is there a blue form? I'm confused

[image]

Comment: so is there a reason why there is two forms? is it just convenience? because at some point I thought that I may have two separate forms on my hands and I don't even remember how I created another one

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/layout-editor.html read this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called a blueprint, it only represents the size of different boxes, not whatever content they have.

[image]

You can choose to see only design / blueprint here or both.